# Project Modules broken after import/open a project (Task generateDebugSources not found)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm starting with AndroidStudio and I getting an error when trying to export the project into the version control:

```
Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'generateDebugSources' not found in project ':app'.

* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get 
  the stacktrace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

The steps to reproduce are:

- Create a new project
- Import the project into the SVN server, excluding the files in the .gitignore:

  ```
  The folder .gradle
  The file .idea/workspace.xml
  The file local.properties
  The folder .idea/libraries
  The folders build
  ```
- Checkout the project from the version control, in AndroidStudio select File/Open.. and open the exported project

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I got this error when I tried to open a project originally created with Eclipse & ADT.

To solve it, try to "export" gradle files from Eclipse and then import it to Android studio (which crashed when I tried to do so but that's another story).  If this is your case as well, please see this link:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-eclipse-projects

Answer (score 0):

I detected the problem:

Adding the .gradle recursivelly also ignored the file app/build.gradle file, breaking the compilation process